# Finding duplicate rows in a Pandas Dataframe then Adding a column in the Dataframe that states if the row is a duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a column with possible duplicates. I would like to create a column that will produce a 1 if the row is duplicate and 0 if it is not.

So if I have:

```
     A|B
1    1|x
2    2|y
3    1|x
4    3|z
```

I would get:

```
     A|B|C
1    1|x|1
2    2|y|0
3    1|x|1
4    3|z|0
```

I tried `df['C'] = np.where(df['A']==df['A'], '1', '0')` but this just created a column of all 1's in C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with parameter `keep=False` for all duplicates first, then cast boolean mask (`True`s and `False`s) to `1`s and `0`s by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) by `int` and if necessary then cast to `str`:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].duplicated(keep=False).astype(int).astype(str)
print (df)
   A  B  C
1  1  x  1
2  2  y  0
3  1  x  1
4  3  z  0
```

If need check duplicates in columns `A` and `B` together use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['C'] = df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False).astype(int).astype(str)
print (df)
   A  B  C
1  1  x  1
2  2  y  0
3  1  x  1
4  3  z  0
```

And [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) solution:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'].duplicated(keep=False), '1', '0')
print (df)
   A  B  C
1  1  x  1
2  2  y  0
3  1  x  1
4  3  z  0
```

Comment: I still received just a column filled with 1's. this was the coded I provided: `df['C'] = df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False).astype(int).astype(str)
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'].duplicated(keep=False), '1', '0')` 
I just provided an example of the dataframe for my question. My real dataframe is about 1 million rows of data, could this be the problem?

Comment: I create 3 solutions, `df['C'] = df['A'].duplicated(keep=False).astype(int).astype(str)` is same as `df['C'] = np.where(df['A'].duplicated(keep=False), '1', '0')` and check dupes only in A column. Do you need one of them? Or need check duplicates in pairs in columns A and B with solution `df['C'] = df.duplicated(subset=['A','B'], keep=False).astype(int).astype(str)` ?

Comment: Also is possiible there are all values duplicates. So you can sort values and check it by `df=df.sort_values('A')` or for A witb B sorting by `df=df.sort_values(['A','B'])`

Comment: Just in column A. I will eventually be creating a function to use C's Boolean to locate the rows. I tried the first solution and just received 1's so I thought I misunderstood and added the np.where as the next line to execute and received the same result.

Comment: Hmmm, do you try sort df by column `A` by `df=df.sort_values('A')` and check if in real data all values are duplicates and then all 1, what is correct output? Because solution works nice, so problem is in data.

Comment: I exported the result to csv and used filters to focus in on the desired output. I should have seen both 0's and 1's in C's column with my filter but all I had was 1's on both duplicates and none duplicates.

Comment: there is something wrong. How do you verify unique values?

Comment: What return `print (df.loc[~df['A'].duplicated(keep=False), 'A'])` ?

Comment: I created a subset that reduced my rows to about 300 which contained both duplicates and non-duplicates and re-ran the code. The majority came back as 1's but the code identified the non-duplicates and marked them with 0's so the code worked on a smaller data set (300 rows x 24 columns). On the larger data set, when I filter with excel, I only get 1's as an option where as with the subset I get both 1's and 0's. Your answer is correct so I will mark it as so and I want to thank you for your help. I just now have to figure out the difference between the two.